# Wordpress -> exclude article category from echoing attribute?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am new to SO and this is my first question here :-)

I have a slider in a WordPress Site that pulls its sub-headlines from the category "work" and adds the attribute "FOR" at the beginning of the sub-headlines. For example:

If an article is sorted in the category: "work -> some text"
the slider will write:

(our company logo)
FOR SOME TEXT

It works fine so far.
But now I have a special case. I have one article/slide that is not allowed to use the attribute "FOR" at the beginning of its sub-headline so that the slider will write:

(our company logo)
SOME TEXT

First I tried to just exclude this particular slide from the "work" category (not a child of "work") but this results in not showing the sub-headline at all.

My code looks like this atm:

```html
<div>
  <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
    <div class="sliderLogo">
      <img class="sliderLogoImg" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/logo_slider.png" alt="" title="">
      <p>
        <?php
          // show child of work-category
          $idObj = get_category_by_slug('work'); 
          $catID = $idObj->term_id; 
          
          foreach((get_the_category()) as $childcat) {
            if (cat_is_ancestor_of($catID, $childcat)) {
              echo 'FOR '.$childcat->cat_name;
            }
          }
        ?>
      </p>
    </div>
    <img src="<?php echo $sliderImg[0]; ?>" alt="">
  </a>
</div>
```

I probably have to insert an "else" statement in the `foreach` part?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stack overflow Boris

the basics of your code are ok, there are a few ways to do this, you can either create an if statemen that checks the ID or add a conditional string. the below example uses a conditional string. replace the 123 by the ID of the category that should not use FOR.

```
<?php
    // show child of work-category
    $idObj = get_category_by_slug('work'); 
    $catID = $idObj->term_id; 
    
    foreach((get_the_category()) as $childcat) {
        if (cat_is_ancestor_of($catID, $childcat)) {
            echo ($childcat->ID==123?"":__("FOR ", "MyTextDomain")).$childcat->cat_name;
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your reply!

unfortunately it didn't work. It showed all the "work" categories as expected, but doesn't write the categories that are not in "work" at all.

With the help of a friend, we figured this out, and it works so far...
(26 is the ID of the category "work" in this case)

```
<?php
// show child of work-category
$idObj = get_category_by_slug(''); 
$childcat=get_the_category();                           

    if ($childcat[0]->category_parent == 26){
    echo 'FOR '.$childcat[0]->cat_name;
                                
} else {

    echo $childcat[0]->cat_name;
}
```

?>